# Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

Tags: jquery, click

these are my js files of my project:

```
tablequerywrapper.js
gauge.min.js
Functions.js
colortip-1.0-jquery.js 
ObjectivesFunctions.js
jquery.bxslider.js
```

in: `Functions.js`, I have:

```
$('li div[id^="objective_option_conversion_points_"]').click(function () {
  alert('3');
}

$('#sortedPixels tbody').sortable({
    items: '> tr',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    placeholder: 'must-have-class',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        // Build a placeholder cell that spans all the cells in the row
        var cellCount = 0;
        $('td, th', ui.helper).each(function () {
            // For each TD or TH try and get it's colspan attribute, and add that or 1 to the total
            var colspan = 1;
            var colspanAttr = $(this).attr('colspan');
            if (colspanAttr > 1) {
                colspan = colspanAttr;
            }
            cellCount += colspan;
        });

        // Add the placeholder UI - note that this is the item's content, so TD rather thanTR
        ui.placeholder.html('<td colspan="' + cellCount + '">&nbsp;</td>');
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

I ran it and got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sortable'
```

I read that this error is because I need `JQUERY UI`, so I added:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the error is gone. but when I pressed a div that has an id = "objective_option_conversion_points_1", nothing is happened.

so I tried:

```
$('li div[id^="objective_option_conversion_points_"]').on('click', function () {
    alert('3');
}
```

but nothing is happened.

so I tried:

```
$('li div[id^="objective_option_conversion_points_"]').live('click', function () {
    alert('3');
}
```

but then I got another error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
```

how can I solve it please?

p.s.

in my jsfiddle, it works:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/adpFV/7/
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: live is deprecated and removed from jQuery

Comment: Are you adding `objective_option_conversion_points_` dynamically if so use event delegation...

Comment: jQuery's `live()` is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I didn't add objective_option_conversion_points_  dynamiccaly. these divs exist in my page.

Comment: how can this topic be duplicate if I tried what they suggested the other topic and it doesn't work??

Comment: `.live()` was removed in version 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live()` is deprecated, and in your jQuery version likely already removed.

You can use [delegates](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for this purpose.

But the selector is just hurting my eyes. Why didn't you use `#` there?

```
$('#objective_option_conversion_points_').on('click', function(){
    alert('3');
});
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work :/

Comment: @AlonShmiel Is the content within the `li` dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1):

Using `on()` is the correct way to go about things:

```
$( 'li' ).on( 'click', 'div[id^="objective ... "]', function () {
    // do something.
}
```

I am not too sure on the syntax to select the div, but the second parameter will 
will listen for any `div[id^="obj ... "]` that are created.

Comment: are you sure you can delegate to `li`? `li`s seem quite susceptible to dynamic addition to me.

Comment: well, this is just a conceptual answer, obviously binding anything on all `li` in a page is silly.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work :/

Comment: @AlonShmiel try bindning to `document` istead of `li`.

Comment: what does it mean? sorry, I didn't understand..

Comment: I tried: .bind("click",function(){

and it doesn't work..